# Using Django-CKeditor and django_comments

Tags: python, django, forms, ckeditor, wysiwyg

couldn't use django-ckeditor with django_comments. I had used with my own apps but there is a weird error on django_comments app.
**I can see and use the editor but on the first time it shows an error**
***'This field is required'.***
**and when I try post same comment again with submit button, I can post it but can't use editor again without page refresh cause of CKeditor locks.**
I use ***django_comments + fluent_comments + threaddedcomments*** it all comes from django_comments. so I should able to use it CKeditor. but I get all the time form error.

I tried to debug it on fluent_comments/views.py since I use *fluent_comments.*

> request.POST.copy() ==> doesn't catch the comment on first time and
>   app shows the error. second time catches and post it but as I said
>   cant use CKEditor again.

***my django_comments form:***

```
class CommentDetailsForm(CommentSecurityForm):
    """
    Handles the specific details of the comment (name, comment, etc.).
    """
    name = forms.CharField(label=pgettext_lazy("Person name", "Name"), max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email address"))
    url = forms.URLField(label=_("URL"), required=False)
    # Translators: 'Comment' is a noun here.
    comment = forms.CharField(label=_('Comment'), widget=CKEditorWidget(),
                              max_length=COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH)
```

***I addded to my fluent_comments form.html:***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text'/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
```

[image: First initial comment posting]

[image]

*no comment data, throws, error 'This field required', posting again, comment posted, ckeditor locks. Im about to get crazy*